# Loading numpy wav audio in wavesurfer

Tags: reactjs, numpy, flask, audio, wavesurfer.js

I have a python backend that generates audio in numpy and I want to be able to load them in wavesurfer.js, by avoiding to write them in a file and to be able to transfer them as a post API call.

I receive a:

```
Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data
```

error.

My python backend is quite standard and looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
DUMMY_AUDIO_PATH = "public/test.wav"

app = Flask(__name__)
def audio_to_js(audio_data):
    # if type is float convert to 64
    if audio_data.dtype == 'float32' or audio_data.dtype == 'float64':
        audio_data = (audio_data * np.iinfo(np.int16).max).astype(np.int16)
    return audio_data.tobytes()

def audio_from_js(audio_data):
    audio = np.frombuffer(audio_data, dtype=np.int16)
    return audio

# Generate audio sample
@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def generate():
    duration = int(request.form.to_dict()['duration'])
    sample_rate, audio_data = read(DUMMY_AUDIO_PATH)
    audio_data = np.array(audio_data, dtype=np.int64)
    return Response(audio_to_js(audio_data), content_type='application/octet-stream')
```

My react-js frontend has the following 3 functions:

```
  const generateSample = useCallback(async () => {
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('duration', duration);
    const response = await fetch(ENDPOINT + '/generate', {method: 'POST', body: body});
    console.log(response);

    if (response.status === 200) {
      const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
      const audio = to_ws(buffer, wavesurferRef.current);
      insert_audio(wavesurferRef.current, audio, -1);
    } else {
      console.log('Error on generate');
    }
  }, []);
```

which should receive, decode and insert the audio to wavesurfer (if it is already initialized insert in the end of the current sample).

The function that breaks and that should convert the received numpy audioBuffer to wavesurfer is:

```
async function to_ws(audio, instance) {
  const offlineAudioContext = instance.backend.ac;
  const decodedAudioBuffer = await offlineAudioContext.decodeAudioData(audio);
  return decodedAudioBuffer;
}
```

and the function that is inserting it in wavesurfer is:

```
function insert_audio(instance, cutSelection, position){
  if (instance.isInitialized) {
    var offlineAudioContext = instance.backend.ac
    var originalAudioBuffer = instance.backend.buffer;
    if (position === -1){
      position = instance.getCurrentTime()
    }
    var newAudioBuffer = offlineAudioContext.createBuffer(
        originalAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
        originalAudioBuffer.length + cutSelection.length,
        originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate);

    for (var channel = 0; channel < originalAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel++) {

        var new_channel_data = newAudioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
        var empty_segment_data = cutSelection.getChannelData(channel);
        var original_channel_data = originalAudioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

        var before_data = original_channel_data.subarray(0, position * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate);
        var mid_data = empty_segment_data
        var after_data = original_channel_data.subarray(Math.floor(position * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate), (originalAudioBuffer.length * originalAudioBuffer.sampleRate));


        new_channel_data.set(before_data);
        new_channel_data.set(mid_data,(position * newAudioBuffer.sampleRate));
        new_channel_data.set(after_data,(position + cutSelection.duration)* newAudioBuffer.sampleRate);
    }
    instance.loadDecodedBuffer(newAudioBuffer);
  }
  else{
    instance.loadDecodedBuffer(cutSelection);
  }

}
```

Can you please help?